# I think something is wrong in what I have done to test a result on co-dimensioning of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing the dimension exercises section of Webner Greub's linear algebra book, but I come across a result that seems to me to be incorrect, here is the exercise: (there is a slightly similar question but in this case I can't use kernel)

´´A subspace $E_1$ of a vector space E is said to have co-dimension n if the factor space $E/E_1$ has dimension n. Let $E_1$ and $F_1$ be subspaces of finite codimension, and let $E_2,F_2$ be complementary subspaces,

$$E_1 \oplus E_2=E$$  $$F_1 \oplus F_2=E$$

Show that $\dim E_2=\operatorname{codim}E_1$ and $\dim F_2=\operatorname{codim}F_1$

The above is easily proved now well my doubt is in the following result:

Prove that $E_1\cap F_1$ has cofinite dimension and that

$$\operatorname{codim}(E_1\cap F_1) \leq \dim(E_2)+\dim(F_2)$$

\begin{align}
\operatorname{codim}(E_1 \cap F_1)&=\dim(E)-\dim(E_1 \cap F_1) \\
&=\dim(E)-(\dim(E_1)+\dim(F_1)-\dim(E_1+F_1))\\
&=\operatorname{codim}(E_1)-\dim(F_1)+\dim(E_1+F_1)  \\
&=\dim(E_2)-\dim(F_1)+\dim(E_1+F_1) \\
&\leq  \dim(E_2)+\dim(E)-\dim(F_1)+\dim(E_1+F_1) \\
&=  \dim(E_2)+\dim(F_2)+\dim(E_1+F_1)
\end{align}

so in this way I have not been able to prove what I wanted in fact I cannot conclude anything

in these inequalities use the following fact:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your proof and the formula you want to use is that they only work if all dimensions are finite, which seems to be not necessarily assumed in the question as given (only certain codimensions are finite).

Now, one of the isomorphism theorems (or probably an easier linear algebra argument ere) says that e.g. $(E_1 + F_1) / F_1 \simeq E_1/(E_1 \cap F_1)$. From this you should be able to conclude that the codimension of $E_1\cap F_1$ **as a subspace of $E_1$** is $\le codim (F_1) = dim(F_2)$.

Further, do you see a general argument why for subspaces $W_2 \subseteq W_1 \subseteq V$, the codimension of $W_2$ in $V$ is finite iff both the codimension of $W_2$ in $W_1$ and that of $W_1$ in $V$ are finite, and in that case it is the sum of them? Then apply this to $V=E, W_1=E_1, W_2=E_1\cap F_1$.